# How to program for two Arduinos with different code but share one same .h?

Tags: arduino-ide

I am now programming for two Arduinos. One is used as Tx and the other is Rx. Of course they are programmed by different codes, but they share some same .h files I programmed(let's say 'share.h'), which are not libraries and shouldn't be put in Arduino's 'library' folder.

So I put 'share.h' and main.ino in one folder, and the ino is like:

```
#include "share.h"
#define TX
#ifdef TX
void setup(){...something for Tx...}
void loop(){...}
#else
void setup(){...something for Rx...}
void loop(){...}
#endif
```

The shortage is that every time I want to update my code to the two unos, I have to: first change the board port to 40(the Tx uno) in ide, add the `#define` line, and upload. Then I have to change port to 42(the Rx one), comment the `#define` line and upload. So inconvenient!

So do you have any good ideas? Much appreciation!

Comment: So, you want a common file, but you don't want to put it in a common file location?

Comment: Are you on a real operating system, or are you using Windows?

Comment: @Majenko Sorry but can't quite follow you. What's a real operating system? I'm using windows 7.

Comment: Then you're not using a real operating system and I can't suggest a way to do it in the Arduino IDE.  If you were using a real operating system like Linux or OS X then you could create a symbolic link so that the share.h file was shared between two locations.  Instead you can't because windows doesn't provide that most basic of facilities.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Er you can say it is, and there may be other ways.

Comment: Something easier than writing or removing two backslashes? Uhm... How can you determine what is the device you want the program to be compiled? Since I suppose that the hardware is the same, the only easier solution I can figure out is to make two different programs and then open them in two different Arduino IDE windows. This way you won't even need to switch port...

Comment: @frarugi87 but then how to share the `share.h`? This is the main problem.

Comment: Modify your hardware to produce a HIGH on a digital input, then have your program decide whether it's TX or RX based on that input.  Then it is always the same code, plus a resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, now I get a better solution. It is changing the `build path` to our working directory, and then we can use relative path!

Here are the deatiled steps:

1. Click IDE's `File-Preferences` and find where it storages `preferences.txt`. Mine is at `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Arduino15\preferences.txt`
2. In the txt file add this line: `build.path=D:\MyProject\ArduinoBuild`. This means let Arduino put the temp files in this directory, such as the `.h` waiting to compile.
3. Because the `.h` Arduino automatically generated from our `.ino` is in `ArduinoBuild` directory, you can now use `#include "./../Share/SomeShare.h"` in order to include the `D:\MyProject\Share\SomeShare.h`

Here is the same question asked in another stackexchange board: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357207/how-to-program-for-two-arduinos-with-different-code-but-share-one-same-h/)

Comment: If your answer worked, select it as the correct answer.

Comment: @lan M It says i can only do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all you have to answer this question:

> How can I tell the compiler what program it should compile?

**The first** (and easiest) solution is to have the preprocessor to this job. It's just a matter of writing two `/`...

Personally, instead of wrapping everything in an `ifdef`, I would have done something like

```
#include "share.h"
#define TX
#ifdef TX
#define setup_tx() setup()
#define loop_tx() loop()
#else
#define setup_rx() setup()
#define loop_rx() loop()
#endif

void setup_tx(){...}
void loop_tx(){...}

void setup_rx(){...}
void loop_rx(){...}
```

This way I could put the two different setup/loop pairs in two different files (e.g. tx.ino and rx.ino). Moreover the `ifdef` block can be moved in an h file.

NOTE: I'm not sure wheter the function redefinition works well, because I never tried it. If it doesn't work you can try doing the opposite (i.e. `#define setup() setup_tx()` and so on) or, in the end, make single-line functions (i.e. `void setup(){setup_tx();}` and so on).

**Another** solution can be applied if the processors are different. For instance if you have an Arduino UNO as transmitter and an Arduino Mega 2560 as a receiver, you could write:

```
#ifdef __AVR_ATmega2560__
- receiver functions
#else
- transmitter functions
#endif
```

But this would require you to switch processor along with the port.

The **third** solution is to place the shared h file in an include directory. You can do this by using a common include dir:

> The include path includes the sketch's directory, the target directory (/hardware/core//) and the avr include directory (/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/), as well as any library directories (in /hardware/libraries/) which contain a header file which is included by the main sketch file.

(See [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess))

You can also pass the `-Idir` option to avr-gcc to include also `dir` in the include dirs list, but this requires you to change the boards.txt file.

The **last** solution I can think at is to compile both programs, load the same files on both arduinos and then choose at runtime what is the correct program to use by assinging a pin to the "choice of program" function.

For instance you assing pin 8 to this function. On the TX board you connect pin 8 to VCC, while on the RX board you connect it to GND. Then the program is:

```
#include "share.h"

// Loop function callback (to speed things up)
typedef void (*loopfunction)();
loopfunction currentloop;

const int RXTX_PIN = 8;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(RXTX_PIN,INPUT);
    if (digitalRead(RXTX_PIN))
    {
        setup_tx();
        currentloop = loop_tx;
    }
    else
    {
        setup_rx();
        currentloop = loop_rx;
    }
}

void loop()
{
    currentloop();
}

void setup_tx(){...}
void loop_tx(){...}

void setup_rx(){...}
void loop_rx(){...}
```

IMHO the best solution is the first one, i.e. the define one. But... You should choose the best for your particular problem.

Bye

Comment: Thanks. But I find another way. See it in my own answer. :) On account of your hard work by commenting such a long answer, I choose your answer as the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 2):

I confronted this exact issue a little while back when writing some sketches that hard shared information. In particular [github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches)

Whilst another IDE may help, I wanted to make my sketches usable by people with the default IDE.

There are a few (annoying) issues here:

- You can't use relative folders as suggested in another answer, because the IDE copies your *current* sketch folder to a temporary folder and compiles from there. It won't copy other nearby folders that happen to be mentioned in .h files.
- You can make soft links (in Linux anyway) as suggested, however that makes it hard to do Git control on them. My first attempt had the link (only) appear in GitHub, which meant that the links didn't compile, once you downloaded them (via the .zip file option in GitHub).
- I switched to hard links, but then had another issue. If you edit a file in the IDE, and save it, evidently this becomes a new file, and so the files in other folders, which are now hard-linked, have the older version and not the newer version.

---

The best solution I could come up with (and I am open to suggestions) was to have a "master" sketch - which has the "real" files you want to include. The other folders have links to them. However if you change the master folder you have to recreate the hard links. I wrote a shell script to do that, but it is still an ugly solution. However since it is a manual process anyway, under Windows you could simply make a copy of the files, when you change the master one.

The other (simpler) alternative would be to make a library, and then simply change the files in that library. That gives you better Git management. The only thing is that you have to edit the library, and then go and test the sketch. It's not that bad.

> And I found that after I added the h as library, no matter how I change the content of the h, the first version is always used in ide.

That shouldn't happen unless the IDE doesn't expect the library to change in-between compiles. If that is the case, even the library idea has flaws.

Comment: Since it is unavailable to use `./../share.h`, I think I may use absolute path. I can define the absolute path of the lib in a .h, and anyone else using my program only need to change this.

Comment: Yes, presuming they have the exact same folder setup as you do. Better not put your name for the home folder, for example. Better hope that they have the sketchbook folder in the same place you have. There are a lot of things that can go wrong there.

Comment: Thanks. And I find another way. See it in my own answer. :)

Comment: @NickGammon Your first point there about relative paths is making a wrong assumption. It's not because the IDE copies the files.  You assume that a relative path is only from the "build" location, but it isn't. It's taken from each of the given include paths (`-I...`) in turn until it's found.  The build location happens to be one of those paths, as are a myriad of others (including all the library paths and system include locations). If the IDE included the sketch folder in the list of includes then you could use relative paths even with it copying files to the build area.  By the way, it ...

Comment: ... doesn't "copy" files at all, but it has all the files open in the IDE and when you compile it saves those files out to the build folder from the IDE, not copy them from the sketch folder.  That's why the IDE doesn't have to save your work when you compile.

Comment: I classify "saving the files" into a temporary folder as *copying* them. I agree that you can compile a file you haven't saved, but surely, that is a **copy** in the build folder. It is a copy of the file you have open in the IDE.

Comment: Anyway, I tried the idea out of using the `../whatever/foo.h` idea and it didn't work, so my assumption wasn't exactly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using Windows there is no easy way of doing what you want to do.

If you were on Linux or OS X you would be able to create a *symbolic link* so that your shared file can exist in more than one location:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/real/share.h share.h
```

On Windows there is then just two options that I can think of:

1. Turn your shared file into a library.  I don't know why you are so adverse to this, since it is by far the simplest option.  Just create a folder "MyProjectShared" in your libraries folder, then name you shared header "MyProjectShared.h" within that folder.  Then `#include <MyProjectShared.h>`.  Of course, choose a sensible name not MyProjectShared.
2. Change to a different IDE that will allow you to add include locations.  One example is my [UECIDE](http://uecide.org/beta) which allows you to add the line:

   #pragma parameter board.flags=-IC:/Path/To/Other/Includes

to the top of your sketch, which adds another location to find header files while compiling.

Another thought has just occurred to me.  If the two sketches are side by side in a folder (say Arduino/Sketch1 and Arduino/Sketch2) then you may be able to use a relative path.

In Sketch2, do:

```
#include "../Sketch1/share.h"
```

Comment: Thx. I don't use library because I use git for my code. If there are a lot of folders dispersing in my computer, it is hard to track them in git(maybe there is a way to approach it?). And I found that after I added the h as library, no matter how I change the content of the h, the first version is always used in ide... I will try the idea tomorrow.

Comment: @Turtle I have just had another thought - take a look at my edit.

Comment: I remembered that Arduino ide doesn't support sub folder. Anyway I will have a try tomorrow.

Comment: @Turtle It doesn't need to - two separate sketches, as long as they are in the same place, you should be able to use a relative path.

Comment: My esthetic preference would be to put share.h in .. instead of in Sketch1, so the include looks like `#include "../share.h"`

Comment: @jwpat7 Or put it in `../shared` so it's `#include "../shared/share.h"`

Comment: @Majenko, yes, that looks like a good alternative

Comment: *"then you may be able to use a relative path"* - surely that doesn't work? The IDE copies files into a temporary folder. It won't copy files from **another** folder in the way you have it.

Comment: @nickgammon it's been so long since I used the Arduino IDE I can't remember if it includes the sketch folder in the list of include paths or not. UECIDE certainly does.

Comment: Even if it did, the build path is not the sketch path. For example `/tmp/build4769560075719248978.tmp/sketch_jul09a.cpp`. So if it went up one level you would go to `/tmp/shared/share.h` which is a directory and file which won't exist.

Comment: Sorry but your last opinion doesn't work. But I find another way based on your opinion. See it in my own answer. :)

Comment: @NickGammon Except that's not how C includes work.  The given path is tried relative to each of the given include paths (`-I...`) until it is found.  "." is normally an implicit include path, though many people choose to add `-I.` to their compilation command anyway.  If the Aduino IDE includes the path to the sketch folder in its include paths (which evidently it doesn't) then it would find `../share/share.h` relative to that path.   See this paste of a test I just performed: http://pastebin.com/hrz4EyVs

Answer (score 1):

You can feed the compiler a [command-line switch](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), `-D<define_name>`, so for your TX you could have a project that has `-DTX` and for the RX `-DRX`.

Then you can share the code between the two projects and you don't need to change the code when you're compiling.

Comment: But how to do this in arduino ide?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
in transmitter.ino
#define TX 1
#include "share.h"

in receiver.ino
#define RX 1
#include "share.h"
```